# постоянное соедение с Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, имеет ли смысл создавать постоянное соединение в php  с помощью mysql_pconnect и как его закрыть? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: функции mysql_* не имеет смысла использовать вообще, они устарели.

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно!

mysql_pconnect() работает аналогично mysql_connect() с двумя отличиями.

Во-первых, при соединении, функция пытается найти уже открытый (постоянный) указатель на тот же сервер с тем же пользователем и паролем. Если он найден, возвращён функцией будет именно он, вместо открытия нового соединения.

Во-вторых, соединение с SQL-сервером не будет закрыто, когда работа скрипта закончится. Вместо этого, оно останется рабочим для будущего использования (mysql_close() также не закрывает постоянные соединения)

Answer (score 0):

Встречал такой алгоритм с базой:

```
 
 1. Проверяем, открыто ли соединение
 2. Открываем соединение если не открыто
 3. Выполняем запрос и продлеваем таймаут ожидания закрытия соединения 
       на  определённую величину
 4. Ждём таймаут, на тот случай, если появятся ещё запросы к базе
 5. закрываем соединение
```

Преимущества метода - экономия процессорного времени на открытие соединения, возможность выполнять prepared statements запросы к базе и экономия соединений если нагрузка велика.
Недостаток метода - сложность реализации.

Comment: А зачем такие сложности, если упомянутый автором [mysql_pconnect](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-pconnect.php) выполняет ту же самую работу в одну строчку?

Comment: а можно поподробнее про таймаут ожидания закрытия и пример, если есть такая возможность?

Comment: в проекте использовалась libpq и с++. Создавался специальный поток, который за этим следил. Не кодил в пахепе. Я б как DBA решил это проще. Ничего не программировать вообще и поставить pgbouncer в режиме "транзакции". Вот и всё кино. Может и под mysql что-то аналогичное поискать?